# Rewrite form in symfony

Tags: symfony

i want to rewrite this form below using form object of symfony 4 and twig.

```
<form class="navbar-form form-search pull-right">
 <input id="search" type="text" class="input-medium search-query">
 <button type="submit" class="btn">rechercher</button>
 </form>
```

How to do that ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. 
What have you tried? Where are you failing?

Answer (score 0):

Symfony have a very large documentation about its components, so this is [Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html), take a tour ;)